# Asp.net MVC, how to avoid slashes(/) in parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[image]

Picture above shows snippets of `Furnitures` table. The user will key-in their desired reference number in `ReferenceNum` field. The problem is, the data itself have slash(/). Everytime the user try to submit the value, my url became `MyWebsite.com/Furniture/PriceList/Ref/3/Case2`, thus the website couldnt find the website.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Reference Number</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RefNum" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="btn btn-success" id="getReference" value="Find"/>
    </div>
</div>

<p id="rData">
</p>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$('#getReference').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Furniture/PriceList/' + $('#RefNum').val(), function (data) {

        var items = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Reference Number</th></tr>';
        $.each(data, function (i, lists) {
            items += "<tr><td>" + lists.ItemName + "</td><td>" + lists.ReferenceNum + "</td></tr>";
        });
        items += "</table>";

        $('#rData').html(items);
    });
})
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult PriceList(string id)
{
    var result = db.Furnitures.Where(x => x.ReferenceNum == id);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Add it as query string value - `'/Furniture/PriceList?id=' + $('#RefNum').val()`

Comment: Oh my...works like a charm! Thank you very much! Can you please repost this in answer box so that I can vote for answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the result as a query string value, rather than a route value

```
$('#getReference').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Furniture/PriceList?id=' + $('#RefNum').val(), function (data) {
```

or

```
$('#getReference').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("PriceList", "Furniture")', { id: $('#RefNum').val() }, function (data) {
```

Comment: oh I didnt know we could use razor in js...i might experiment on this..thank you once again

Comment: You should always use `@Url.Action()` to generate your urls :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%2F` to escape slash(/) character in URL.

So updated JS code will be:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$('#getReference').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Furniture/PriceList/' + $('#RefNum').val().replace(/\//g,'%2F'), function (data) {   //<--- Fix

        var items = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Reference Number</th></tr>';
        $.each(data, function (i, lists) {
            items += "<tr><td>" + lists.ItemName + "</td><td>" + lists.ReferenceNum + "</td></tr>";
        });
        items += "</table>";

        $('#rData').html(items);
    });
})
```

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: Please look updated answer at `$('#RefNum').val().replace(/\//g,'%2F')`

Comment: it works but the problem is, the query could not find the data

Comment: Please inspect value of `string id` at server-side. It should be intact.